# Unnable to sync Jcenter to Maven Central

Tags: maven, bintray, jcenter

I am trying to sync my bintray repo to maven, yet I receive the following error:

```
Last Synced: Never
Last Sync Status: Sync Failed
Last Sync Errors: Problem extracting files to sync. Please try again in a bit.
```

Here is my repo: https://bintray.com/ionut-damian/maven/ssj
There is currently one version of the library committed. It was committed 4 days ago. The library is both in my private bintray as well as on jcenter.

Any ideas?

Comment: I have the exact same problem

Comment: Same here........

Comment: It seems it is working again